# Iterate Dependency Graph items generated by Stanford Dependency Parser

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

I am struggling to go over the results of Stanford Dependency Parser. It prints the information successfully but I can't access it. This is what I see when I print the results.

```
defaultdict(<function DependencyGraph.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x075078A0>,
                        {0: {'address': 0,
                             'ctag': 'TOP',
                             'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'root': [2]}),
                             'feats': None,
                             'head': None,
                             'lemma': None,
                             'rel': None,
                             'tag': 'TOP',
                             'word': None},
                         1: {'address': 1,
                             'ctag': 'CD',
                             'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
                             'feats': '_',
                             'head': 2,
                             'lemma': '_',
                             'rel': 'nummod',
                             'tag': 'CD',
                             'word': 'seven'},
```

How can I acess these items?

Comment: result = parser.parse('seven leaf')
print(result[0])

Comment: the above returns TypeError: 'list_iterator' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Since it says it's an iterator have you tried `print(result.next())` ? Weird because the result should be a defaultdict as in your question...

Answer (score 1):

The output of the dependency graph is an object of `DependencyGraph` class. If you run

```
dir(result) # assuming result contains the parser output
```

You would be able to see all the properties and methods of the `result` object.

```
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__unicode__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_hd',
 '_parse',
 '_rel',
 '_repr_svg_',
 '_tree',
 '_word',
 'add_arc',
 'add_node',
 'connect_graph',
 'contains_address',
 'contains_cycle',
 'get_by_address',
 'get_cycle_path',
 'left_children',
 'load',
 'nodes',
 'nx_graph',
 'redirect_arcs',
 'remove_by_address',
 'right_children',
 'root',
 'to_conll',
 'to_dot',
 'top_relation_label',
 'tree',
 'triples',
 'unicode_repr']
```

Then you can iterate over all nodes to access your desired items.

```
for i in range(len(result.nodes)):
    print(f"Word: {result.nodes[i]['word']}\tLemma: {result.nodes[i]['lemma']}\tTag: {result.nodes[i]['tag']}\tHead: {result.nodes[i]['head']}\tRel: {result.nodes[i]['rel']}")
```